# import .sql file into mysql from mac command line. tried mysql -u root -p db_name > path/to/dbfile.sql

Tags: mysql, bash, zsh

I have tried doing it from the command line

```
mysql -u root -p db_name > ~/Documents/db_name.sql
```

I have tried doing it from mysqlimport

```
mysqlimport -u root -p db_name ~/Documents/db_name.sql
```

I have tried both while being in the correct directory using just the file name.

I have tried entering mysql using

```
mysql -u root -p
use db_name;
source ~/Documents/db_name.sql;
(nothing happens - no response)
(tried with absolute path - no response)
\. ~/Documents/db_name.sql
(nothing happens)
```

I feel like I'm missing something. This seems like a trivial operation according to the last 30 minutes of googling and attempts.

Ultimately I had to copy and paste the entire .sql file into the mysql shell while using the correct db.

I feel like a caveman. Please help.

Edit: SQL file contents

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.15.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1:8889
-- Generation Time: May 09, 2017 at 09:27 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.34-log
-- PHP Version: 7.0.13

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `movie-buff`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `directors`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `directors` (
  `director_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `directors`
--

INSERT INTO `directors` (`director_id`, `first`, `last`, `country`) VALUES
(1, 'Jean-Pierre', 'Jeunet', 'France'),
(2, 'Jean', 'Renoir', 'France'),
(3, 'Akira', 'Kurosawa', 'Japan'),
(4, 'Jane', 'Campion', 'New Zealand'),
(5, 'Sally', 'Potter', 'UK'),
(6, 'Kasi', 'Lemmons', 'USA'),
(7, 'Ava', 'DuVernay', 'USA'),
(8, 'Todd', 'Haynes', 'USA'),
(9, 'Marleen', 'Gorris', 'Netherlands');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `movies`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movies` (
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(130) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `director_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `movies`
--

INSERT INTO `movies` (`movie_id`, `title`, `year`, `director_id`) VALUES
(1, 'The City of Lost Children', 1995, 1),
(2, 'Amelie', 2001, 1),
(3, 'The Rules of the Game', 1939, 2),
(4, 'La Grande Illusion', 1937, 2),
(5, 'The Lower Depths', 1936, 2),
(6, 'Alien: Resurrection', 1997, 1),
(7, 'Ran', 1985, 3),
(8, 'Seven Samurai', 1954, 3),
(9, 'Throne of Blood', 1957, 3),
(10, 'An Angel at My Table', 1990, 4),
(11, 'The Piano', 1993, 4),
(12, 'Orlando', 1992, 5),
(13, 'The Tango Lesson', 1997, 5),
(14, 'Talk to Me', 2007, 6),
(15, 'Eve''s Bayou', 1997, 6),
(16, 'Selma', 2014, 7),
(18, 'Far From Heaven', 2002, 8),
(19, 'I''m Not There', 2007, 8),
(20, 'Carol', 2015, 8),
(21, 'Antonia''s Line', 1995, 9),
(22, 'Mrs. Dalloway', 1997, 9);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `viewers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `viewers` (
  `viewer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `viewers`
--

INSERT INTO `viewers` (`viewer_id`, `first`, `last`, `email`) VALUES
(1, 'Tim', 'Labonne', 'tim_labonne@live.com'),
(2, 'Alicen', 'Brightley', 'abrightley@yahoo.com'),
(3, 'Renard', 'Sartor', 'rsartor@washu.edu'),
(4, 'Luigi', 'Greco', 'elgreco@live.com'),
(5, 'Jackie', 'Linwood', 'jLinwood@yahoo.com'),
(6, 'Caroline', 'Smith', 'youknowwho@live.com');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `viewings`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `viewings` (
  `viewing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `viewer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_viewed` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `viewings`
--

INSERT INTO `viewings` (`viewing_id`, `viewer_id`, `movie_id`, `date_viewed`) VALUES
(1, 1, 4, '2008-10-07'),
(2, 1, 2, '2009-12-18'),
(3, 1, 1, '2010-02-27'),
(4, 1, 21, '2010-03-14'),
(5, 2, 21, '2015-04-15'),
(6, 2, 22, '2015-10-04'),
(7, 2, 7, '2015-11-30'),
(8, 2, 9, '2016-01-05'),
(9, 2, 12, '2016-04-14'),
(10, 2, 16, '2017-01-23'),
(11, 3, 8, '2016-02-14'),
(12, 3, 18, '2016-03-20'),
(13, 3, 22, '2016-04-07'),
(14, 4, 20, '2017-01-03'),
(15, 4, 18, '2017-01-14'),
(16, 4, 15, '2017-02-08'),
(17, 4, 10, '2007-09-23'),
(18, 4, 2, '2017-03-05'),
(19, 4, 4, '2017-04-13'),
(20, 4, 12, '2017-04-30'),
(21, 4, 14, '2017-05-02'),
(22, 4, 21, '2017-05-08'),
(23, 5, 2, '2013-08-25'),
(24, 5, 3, '2013-12-16'),
(25, 5, 7, '2014-03-18'),
(26, 6, 11, '2013-11-30'),
(27, 6, 2, '2013-12-18'),
(28, 6, 14, '2014-04-29'),
(29, 6, 5, '2016-12-03'),
(30, 6, 13, '2017-01-09'),
(31, 6, 18, '2017-02-13'),
(32, 6, 21, '2017-03-14'),
(33, 6, 15, '2017-04-15');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `directors`
--
ALTER TABLE `directors`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`director_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `movies`
--
ALTER TABLE `movies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`),
  ADD KEY `director_id` (`director_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `viewers`
--
ALTER TABLE `viewers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`viewer_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `viewings`
--
ALTER TABLE `viewings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`viewing_id`),
  ADD KEY `viewer_id` (`viewer_id`),
  ADD KEY `movie_id` (`movie_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `directors`
--
ALTER TABLE `directors`
  MODIFY `director_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `movies`
--
ALTER TABLE `movies`
  MODIFY `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=23;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `viewers`
--
ALTER TABLE `viewers`
  MODIFY `viewer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `viewings`
--
ALTER TABLE `viewings`
  MODIFY `viewing_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=34;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `movies`
--
ALTER TABLE `movies`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `movies_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`director_id`) REFERENCES `directors` (`director_id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `viewings`
--
ALTER TABLE `viewings`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `viewings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`viewer_id`) REFERENCES `viewers` (`viewer_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `viewings_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movies` (`movie_id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: What is the content of the `.sql` file?.

Comment: @wchiquito updating now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the `mysql` command in order to import a mysqldump sql file:

`mysql -u root -p db_name < ~/Documents/db_name.sql`

The `mysqlimport` utility is used to insert data from textfiles into the database, it is a wrapper around the `LOAD DATA INFILE` sql statement. From [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) documentation:

> The mysqlimport client provides a command-line interface to the LOAD
>   DATA INFILE SQL statement. Most options to mysqlimport correspond
>   directly to clauses of LOAD DATA INFILE syntax. See Section 13.2.6,
>   “LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax”.

Comment: i did this mysql -u root -p db_name > ~/Documents/db_name.sql  as well as using < (once i realized my mistake).

Comment: do you need to create an empty database on that user before using this command?

Comment: If the database `db_name` does not exist then yes. Do `mysql -u root -p -e 'CREATE DATABASE dbname'` before the import.

Comment: alright. that is what i read as well. i feel like i followed all of the correct steps. im very confused. first time using mysql

Comment: Your sql dump file starts with this: `USE movie-buff;` which assumes that you already have an existing `movie-buff` database.

Comment: ya. it has definitely been created. i kept checking the tables on it to see if it worked. it kept outputting "empty set"

Comment: Are you sure your `directors` table is empty? According to your sql file the table should be created (`CREATE TABLE ...`) and the data inserted (`INSERT INTO ...`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162581/discussion-between-vampiire-and-marcell).

Comment: `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'db_name'`

Comment: @sK500 the above example imports a mysql dump into an existing database called `db_name`. If it does not exist, it has to be created first with the `CREATE DATABASE db_name;` command.

Comment: @marcell I know, I already had a `.sql` file with `create database db_name` and `use db_name` which I used according to your suggestion. For some reason it gave me that weird error then worked later so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce the problem:

File: `~/Documents/db_name.sql`

```bsh
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `movie-buff`;

USE `movie-buff`;

--
-- Table structure for table `directors`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `directors` (
  `director_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `directors`
--

INSERT INTO `directors` (`director_id`, `first`, `last`, `country`)
VALUES
(1, 'Jean-Pierre', 'Jeunet', 'France'),
(2, 'Jean', 'Renoir', 'France'),
(3, 'Akira', 'Kurosawa', 'Japan'),
(4, 'Jane', 'Campion', 'New Zealand'),
(5, 'Sally', 'Potter', 'UK'),
(6, 'Kasi', 'Lemmons', 'USA'),
(7, 'Ava', 'DuVernay', 'USA'),
(8, 'Todd', 'Haynes', 'USA'),
(9, 'Marleen', 'Gorris', 'Netherlands');
```

MySQL:

```sql
mysql> source ~/Documents/db_name.sql
Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

It also works with:

- `mysql> \. ~/Documents/db_name.sql`
- `$ mysql -u user -p movie-buff < ~/Documents/db_name.sql`

**UPDATE**

In the case of `mysql> source ~/Documents/db_name.sql`, `mysql> \. ~/Documents/db_name.sql` and `$ mysql -u user -p < ~/Documents/db_name.sql` (without specifying the database) the database may not be created, but must be created in the script (see script above). In the case of `$ mysql -u user -p movie-buff < ~/Documents/db_name.sql` the database must be created before.

Comment: did you create the database before doing all of this? maybe that is my problem? i created an empty one and then tried populating it from the file